# Why do I get 'Failed to compile error' in angular12 after looping an empty array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I used angular material to create an accordion that suppose to display several posts:

```
  <mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf="posts.length > 0">
   <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
   <mat-expansion-panel-header>
   <mat-panel-title> {{ post.title }} </mat-panel-title>
   </mat-expansion-panel-header>
     <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
   </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
  <p class="mat-body-1" *ngIf="posts.length === 0">No posts added 
   yet</p>
```

In my .ts file I loop over posts array and everything works fine as long as it contains the post objects

```
 posts = [{ title: 'first post', content: 'this is the 1 post'}, { 
 title: 'second post', content: 'this is the 2 post' },
 { title: 'third post', content: 'this is the 3 post'},
 ];
```

As soon as I empty the posts array in order to see the 'P' tag with 'No posts added yet' and than try to loop over it I get 'failed to compile error' even though I check beforehand that the array length is greater than 0.
What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you try to structure your code again to make it a bit more readable? :-) Also, please add information on where the posts array is being filled and what "<code>" means here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to check if posts exists before :

```
*ngIf="posts && posts.length > 0">
```

Answer (score 0):

can you reframe your question, not sure what you are trying to say exactly,
I have replicated your code and it's working, check here - [LiveDemo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-sjjrmn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Your answer helped me solve it.
I needed to initialize it like so : posts: { title: string; content: string }[] = [];

now it works.
Thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped you! Can you please vote my answer

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I needed to initialized the posts[].

Like so: posts: { title: string; content: string }[] = [];